# Is 'kata nana' a synonym for 'pativedha nana'?

Tags: vipassana, pali

Is 'kata nana' a synonym for 'pativedha nana'?

I wonder if there is a (slight) difference between these two words. Can they be used as synonyms?

Comment: Kata = goodness, giving, worked, done, made; pativedha = insight, penetrating; ñāṇa = knowledge. Maybe good to know the context where it is used. katanana ~ knowledge of that there is giving "there are gifts, sacrifies"; pativedha ~ knowledge about penetration. Common is the word kataññū-pativedha, penetration of gratitude. It could be also confused with common "katavedin" grateful and mindful of benefits.

Answer (score 1):

'Pativedha nana' is the full-blown development of insight knowledge which occurs when ñana-nana-sampayutta dhammas cease to exist. It has absolutely nothing to do with 'kata nana'.

'Kata nana' is a very preliminary form of insight knowledge which means that one is realizing the impermanence of all dhammas (including ñana, nana, and panna). Perhaps better to say that one has, at the very least, realized the impermanence of all dhammas in the 6 sense spheres.